# classes with CRUD methods violating Single Responsibility principle?

Tags: spring, solid-principles, single-responsibility-principle

I am trying to understand single responsibility principle. I have following questions.

1. The Single Responsibility Principle (SRP) states that there should never be 
   more than one reason for a class to change. 
   Usually our Resource,Service and Repository classes have
   create,read,update and delete method. We are changing each class to
   modify code for any any of these operations. Is it violating SRP? Do we need 
   separate class for each action?
2. When I run sonar lint, I have seen below message.

   Classes should not coupled to too many other classes.

   Here I am injecting other classes using spring DI. Is there any limit on 
   number of dependencies?

I may be missing crux of this concept. Please suggest a good resource for understanding this concept better with examples

Comment: What are the responsibilities of those injected classes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The SRP states that the class should only do one thing, like persisting entities in the case of repositories. I guess that you've confused "class" and "object" here: if you have several methods that could change the *object*'s state this could be in accordance with the SRP. However the only reason for a repository *class* to change should have something to do with its purpose, namely persisting or retrieving entities in this case.

The Wikipedia article about the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) puts it very well.

To your second point: there is no such thing as a maximum number of dependencies a class can have, but it could be a sign for a design weakness if there are many of them.

Answer (score 3):

> The Single Responsibility Principle (SRP) states that there should
>   never be more than one reason for a class to change.

The Single Responsibility principle doesn't mean a single method or a single type of action by component/class.
It means a **single responsibility in the scope of a matter**.

Persistence operations makes part of the same matter.
So putting all of them in a single class doesn't violate necessary the principle.

Now if you have dozen and dozen of specific database operations, it would make sense to divide them into distinct classes having a well defined responsibility such as selecting operations, updating operations, and so for.

> Usually our Resource,Service and Repository classes have
>   create,read,update and delete method. We are changing each class to
>   modify code for any any of these operations. Is it violating SRP?

These are distinct layers.
If you change the model of a layer, others are very often impacted as data passes between layers.
It is like if you add an information in your database, you necessary need to change your GUIs and your processing if you want see/manipulate them.

Now if you change implementation of layers, other layers should have no or very few consequences.

Comment: I would argue that Persistence is *not* a domain responsibility. It's a purely technical one. Requirements usually say: User should be able to transfer cash from one account to the other, or: User should be able to borrow a book. Specifications (the business) is usually not about CRUD.

Comment: Also, "if you add an information in your database, you necessary need to change your GUIs and your processing" ? So that means things that change together are not actually together?

Comment: @Robert Bräutigam "Persistence is not a domain responsibility". I agree. I referenced it as  "matter/domain". Not as business domain. I will edit to be clearer. About the second point, it is not wrong. But you can do nothing with that as you use layers and abstraction. It favors a cleaner code but you have to bridge them.

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between **responsiblity and function**.
If a class was suppose to have only 1 function, we would have only 1 public method per class. Defination of responsiblity is crucial. For ex. if we have a string manipulator class, its responsiblity is string manupulation. It can have multiple functions - reverse, upperCase, LowerCase, truncate.
All functions realted to string manupulation responsiblity can be part of the class. But if we try to add a stranger functionality like string conversion or string printing, that would break SRP.
So, as long as your functions/ methods are under the umberalla of the responsiblity of the class, you are following SRP.